# how to call a stored procedure in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am new at this. I am trying to just run a procedure.

My procedure is this:

```
create or replace procedure temp_proc is

    begin
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
    end
```

this executes fine:

but when I try to call it using this:

```
begin 
    temp_proc;
end;
```

It shows temp_proc is invalid.

How do you call a procedure in oracle pl/sql please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure's code misses semi-colon after `end`; if you ran it in SQL*Plus, it misses a slash as well. Other than that, it *works*:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure temp_proc is
  2
  3      begin
  4        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
  5      end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2      temp_proc;
  3  end;
  4  /
Test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: No it is still showing that error I am talking about pl/sql developer

Comment: I can't comment PL/SQL Developer (Allround Automations' GUI tool, right?) as I don't use it. As far as Oracle and PL/SQL language is concerned, everything is fine - as I demonstrated. If you can't make it work, then - I presume - it is about usage of the tool. I suggest you do what I said: use semi-colon to terminate `end` and put a slash into the next line.